# If statement not executing correct code?

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to develop a Tic Tac Toe game for practice with javascript but I've hit a roadblock. I have an if statement that should be returning true but it isn't.  Here is a sample.

```
var game = true;
var x = 'X';
var o = 'O';
var blank = '';

var turn = x;
var board = [blank, blank, blank,
             blank, blank, blank,
             blank, blank, blank];

function write() {

    $('td').click(function() {
        //Making sure that the block that was clicked can only be clicked once
        var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
        var digit = parseInt(id.slice(-1));
        //check to see of the block has been clicked on
        if (board[digit] = blank) {
            board[digit] = turn;
            $(board[digit]).html(turn.toUpperCase());
            if (turn = x) {
                turn = o;
            } else if (turn = o) {
                turn = x;
            }

        } else {
            alert("That box has already been clicked on!")
        }
    }); 

}
```

Comment: `=` is for **assignment**, `==` or `===` are for comparison.

Comment: by the way, you should really look into turning that one dimension array into something like `[[b, b, b], [b, b, b], [b, b, b]]`, just a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues at first glance.

First, `event` is undefined. Define it as a function parameter in your `.click` call.

```js
 $('td').click(function(event) { /* rest of the code */ }
```

Second, as Pointy commented, `=` is for assignment, `==` and `===` are meant for comparisons.
Thus

```js
if (board[digit] = blank) { /**/ }
```

needs to be

```js
if (board[digit] === blank) { /**/ }
```

Regarding the difference between `==` and `===` you can get more information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Short version, prefer `===` unless you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing and want to explicitly use `==`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (board[digit] === blank) {
                   ^^
```